# Android NDK: can we use C++ for all work

Tags: android, android-ndk

I recently know that we can use Android NDK (use C++ language) to program. But, I'm afraid that, can we use Android NDK to do most of work in Android ? (because people just say that NDK just helps increasing performance of an android program)

I see that ADT plugin for eclipse is powerful, but It's for java. So, if I want to develop on `Android NDK`, does it has a plugin same with that.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is well-supported on Android: there are books, tutorials, Google results and a lot of similar documentation and resources. Developing with the NDK has less stuff available.

Although you can in principle write your full application in C++ using the [NativeActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html), I believe that you will have less resources at your disposal for that, compared to Java. If you really want to make your Java program faster, you should profile it, to find which part needs this performance gain and write only that part in C++ using JNI.

Answer (score 0):

you could, but it is not recommend. For one c++ and java performance for multiple aspects are equivalent, then every jni call has its overhead that you have to take in account. Take a look to this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#native_methods)